# Protractor webdriver-manager update occurs events.js:161 - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm, protractor, webdriver-manager

I installed npm install protractor -g and tried afterwards to update 
webdriver-manager with the command "webdriver-manager update" and it occurs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CbmQ.png)

If I try to start the webdriver-manager with the command "webdriver-manager start" it says, "Selenium Standalone is not present. Install with webdriver-manager update --standalone" 
Here ist the Setup-Tutorial: http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial

I don't know what to do, can u help me?

Comment: Did Protractor install correctly?  Check your version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDriver Manager downloads essential drivers on `update`. Not sure of you are running it from a docker container, vagrant VM or inside a VPN.

It downloads from the below source and the ipaddress in your screenshot indicates you are facing an issue connecting to `https://github.com/mozilla`. On pinging github I see same IP.

Sources: from [webdriver-manager configs](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/master/config.json)

```
  "cdnUrls": {
    "selenium": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "chromedriver": "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "geckodriver": "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/",
    "iedriver": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "androidsdk": "http://dl.google.com/android/"
  }
```

Can you ping as shown below and see if you are able to access the above sources(Chrome & seleniumServer & Gecko) manually from the location where you are doing the `webdriver-manager update`

```
C:\Users\<<>>\WebstormProjects\demo>ping github.com

Pinging github.com [192.30.253.112] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.30.253.112: bytes=32 time=207ms TTL=47
Reply from 192.30.253.112: bytes=32 time=205ms TTL=47
Reply from 192.30.253.112: bytes=32 time=205ms TTL=47
Reply from 192.30.253.112: bytes=32 time=205ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 192.30.253.112:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 205ms, Maximum = 207ms, Average = 205ms
```